# Find the value of this Limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Find the value of,
$$\lim_{x\to \infty}\left(\dfrac{x+15}{x+3}\right)^{\large{\ln\left(\sin{\frac{1}{x}}\right)}}$$

I've tried putting it in exponential log form and then apply l'Hospital rule but that derivative is giving me a headache.

Comment: Think about a quite obvious substitution.

Comment: Sorry but I can't see how a substitution can help here!

Comment: And I can't see what "obvious" substitution can help here.

Comment: Try $x=\frac 1y$

Comment: Still (1^∞) @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: Continue in the spirit of Aaron Maroja's answer. Think about Taylor series.

Comment: Be wary of my answer - there's something wrong with it (looking into it now)

Answer (score 5):

The obvious substitution to make is $x=1/t$, that transforms your limit into
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\left(\frac{15+1/t}{3+1/t}\right)^{\ln\sin t}
$$
Now it's time to try the logarithm of this:
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\ln\sin t\ln\left(\frac{15+1/t}{3+1/t}\right)=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\ln\sin t\ln\left(\frac{15t+1}{3t+1}\right)
$$
Consider, for the moment,
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{1}{t}\ln\left(\frac{15t+1}{3t+1}\right)=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\ln(15t+1)-\ln(3t+1)}{t}
$$
which is good for using l'Hôpital's theorem:
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\ln(15t+1)-\ln(3t+1)}{t}\overset{\mathrm{(H)}}{=}
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\dfrac{15}{15t+1}-\dfrac{3}{3t+1}}{1}=12
$$
On the other hand,
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}t\ln\sin t=\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\ln\sin t}{1/t}
\overset{\mathrm{(H)}}{=}
\lim_{t\to0^+}\frac{\dfrac{\cos t}{\sin t}}{-\dfrac{1}{t^2}}
=
\lim_{t\to0^+}-t\cos t\frac{t}{\sin t}=0
$$
Thus
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}\ln\sin t\ln\left(\frac{15t+1}{3t+1}\right)
=
\lim_{t\to0^+}(t\ln\sin t)\cdot\left(\frac{1}{t}\ln\left(\frac{15t+1}{3t+1}\right)\right)=0\cdot 12=0
$$

**Therefore your original limit is $\boxed{e^0=1}$**

---

#### Note

Why multiplying and dividing by $t$? The reason is that
$$
\ln\frac{15t+1}{3t+1}=\ln(15t+1)-\ln(3t+1)=15t+o(t)-(3t+o(t))=12t+o(t)
$$
so “it counts as $12t$”. Dividing it by $t$ leaves a finite nonzero limit, which is never a cause of indetermination.

Thus we are left with $\lim_{t\to0^+}t\ln\sin t$ and this is very similar to $\lim_{t\to0^+}t\ln t=0$. Without l'Hôpital's theorem one could do by
$$
\lim_{t\to0^+}t\ln\sin t=
\lim_{t\to0^+}t\ln\left(t\frac{\sin t}{t}\right)=
\lim_{t\to0^+}\left(t\ln t+ t\ln\frac{\sin t}{t}\right)
$$
and both summands have zero limit.

Comment: +1 Very nice answer, yet the substitution is "obvious" only after all the nice job above is done, otherwise it is "obvious" that one gets an expression almost as wild as the original one. In particular the development following "Consider, for the moment...", is very nice, yet it is as far from obvious as one could expect, and without it I can't see how to reach the solution in a more or less decent form.

Comment: The limit is 1 though, I checked this on a calculator (and worked out where the critical points are myself) it monotonically increases after a minimum above 0

Comment: @Timbuc I have added the note for explaining *why* attempting the insertion of $t/t$. As regards the “obvious” substitution, I find that often it's easier to compute limits at $0$ than at $\infty$; maybe it's just psychological. But in this case it changes the wild $\sin(1/x)$ into a tamer $\sin t$.

Comment: @AlecTeal Yes, of course: $0$ is the limit of the logarithm of the whole thing! However I added for clarity.

Comment: Oh missed that!

Answer (score 1):

Take $y = \frac{1}{x}$ then $y \to 0$ when $x \to \infty$ and

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \Bigg(\frac{1 + \frac{15}{x}}{1+\frac{3}{x}}\Bigg)^{\ln(\sin \frac{1}{x})} =\lim_{y\to 0} \Bigg(\frac{1 + 15y}{1+3y}\Bigg)^{\ln(\sin y)} $$

Comment: So what's the difference? It's still indetermination(no better form)

Comment: Missed the sin, but it's okay because of small angle approximations

Comment: @AlecTeal Thanks!

Comment: I fixed a small typo ! Happy New Year !!!

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks! Happy New Year neighbor!!

Answer (score 1):

It's enough to determine the limit of the logarithm: $$\ln\Bigl(\sin\dfrac{1}{x}\Bigr)\ln\frac{x+15}{x+3}=\ln(\sin y)\bigl(\ln(1+15y)-\ln(1+3y)\bigr)\underset 0 \sim 12y\ln(\sin y)$$
if we set $y=\dfrac 1 x$.

Now set $u=\sin y, u\in [-\frac\pi 2,\frac\pi 2]$, i.e. $y=\arcsin u$. Then
$$12y\ln(\sin y)=12\arcsin u\ln u\underset{0_+} \sim 12u\ln u\underset{u\to 0_+}\longrightarrow 0_{-}.$$

Hence the original expression tends to $1$ from below.